# How do you restore DTS permissions after database restore on SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, dts

As part of the way we handle support for our clients for an enterprise application, we have them backup their database, I restore it on our server, do some maintenance, backup it up, and have them restore it on their server.  This works very well, but I usually have to reset the users permissions for that database.  But at the moment I have one client that is not able to run the DTS packages on that server due to a database user not being able to connect to the database.  I've tried looking through every possible setting and option as well as checked and rechecked the permissions for that user, who by the way is in the dbo role, but nothing seems to work.  Anyone know why I can't connect even though the user has the correct permissions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of the database might be wrong. I'd check that first by making sure the owner is set to a user or role on their network (or sa if they're not using Windows authentication).